# EPiServer Remote Certification Exam Registration Purchase Order

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2, episerver-8

While registering for the upcoming EPiServer certification exam, the sign up page shows a field named "Purchase order/Invoice Reference *" under Invoice Details section. I don't have such a Purchase order/Invoice Reference. Also its a mandatory field.

Please let me know what should I enter in this field? Is there any prior purchase required for attending the exam?

Any one have EPiServer exam registration knowledge please suggest.

Here is the URL I am trying to register with

http://www.episerver.com/Training/Schedule--registration/Course-registration/?occasionId=0e8851f7-b5b7-e611-80ef-fc15b426ff90

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just an internal reference for whoever receives the invoice at your company. It could be your name, or if you have an internal purchase order system, the purchase order reference code. Just so the invoice receiver know what it's all about.